# WebGL rotating over a given center

Tags: javascript, rotation, webgl

So I have a XML document that I parse in order to execute actions in a WebGL scene.
So I have Nodes that can or cannot be animated.
Then I have a CircularAnimation that has a Center(x, y, z) that the Node should rotate around with a Radius distance from that center. A Span of time for the Animation, a satrting Angle and a Rotation Angle.

```
<ANIMATION id="cir1" span="5" type="circular" center="0 0 0" radius="3" startang="0" rotang="360"/>
```

In my CircularAnimation class I have a function to make the object move and update it's horizontal orientation. Similar to the way the earth rotates over the sun.

I use the currTime defined in the Animation class to calculate if the span has ended or not.

```
if(this.beg_time == null) this.beg_time = currTime;
else 
{
    if((currTime-this.beg_time) >= this.span) return;
    else 
    {
        // Calculates angles to rotate
        var ang_inc = (this.angle_rot*(currTime-this.beg_time))/this.span;
        var total_rot = ang_inc+this.angle_beg;

        // Rotates node Matrix from the Matrix_Beg
        mat4.rotateY(this.node.matrix, this.node.beg_matrix, total_rot);


        // Moves the node to the desired center
        mat4.translate(this.node.matrix, this.node.matrix, [this.x, this.y, this.z]);

        // Moves the node according to the given radius
        mat4.translate(this.node.matrix, this.node.matrix, [this.radius*Math.cos(ang_inc), 0, this.radius*Math.sin(ang_inc)]);
    }
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work properly, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little background first just in case:

If you have a vertex `v` that should be transformed by `beg_matrix` to get `v'`, the matrix multiplication will look like `v' = beg_matrix * v`. If you then want to translate `v'` by matrix `T` to get `v''` the equation will be similar: `v'' = T * v'`. Now if we want to go straight from vertex `v` to vertex `v''` we can sort of mash the two equations together (sustitute `v'`) and get `v'' = T * beg_matrix * v`. This is essentially what you are trying to do except `T` needs to be a matrix that yields rotation around a center point.

I believe when the glMatrix library you seem to be using applies transformations, the transforms are applied on the *right-hand* side of the previous matrix (`v'' = beg_matrix * T * v`) which applies the new transformations before any previous ones (not what you want).

If you reverse all your transformations and apply them to a new matrix, then multiply this new matrix on the *left-hand* side of `beg_matrix`, I believe it should get you closer to what you're looking for.

I haven't run this code since it's obviously part of a larger project that wasn't provided but it should get the point across.

```js
if(this.beg_time == null) this.beg_time = currTime;
else 
{
    if((currTime - this.beg_time) >= this.span) return;
    else
    {
        // Calculates angles to rotate
        var ang_inc = (angle_rot * (currTime - this.beg_time)) / this.span;
        var total_rot = ang_inc + this.angle_beg;

        // Start with the identity matrix and no transformations.
        // Our end goal is a matrix M where M = T * C * R * beg_matrix.
        // T - radial translation
        // C - translation to center point
        // R - rotation by angle
        // beg_matrix - previous transformations
        mat4.identity(this.node.matrix);

        // Moves the node according to the given radius
        // M = T
        mat4.translate(this.node.matrix, this.node.matrix, [this.radius*Math.cos(total_rot), 0, this.radius*Math.sin(total_rot)]);

        // Moves the node to the desired center
        // M = T * C
        mat4.translate(this.node.matrix, this.node.matrix, [this.x, this.y, this.z]);

        // Rotates node Matrix from the Matrix_Beg
        // M = T * C * R
        // (negative angle since the library rotates clockwise along [0, 1, 0]?)
        mat4.rotateY(this.node.matrix, this.node.beg_matrix, -total_rot);

        // apply previous transformations
        // M = T * C * R * beg_matrix
        mat4.multiply(this.node.matrix, this.node.matrix, this.node.beg_matrix);
    }
}
```

Also in your previous code you were using `ang_inc` in your cosine and sine calculations and I think you might have wanted `total_rot`? Anyway hope this helps! Cheers!